# How to plot loss curve in Tensorflow without using Tensorboard?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

Hey I am new to Tensorflow. I used DNN to train the model and I would like to plot  the loss curve. However, I do not want to use Tensorboard since I am really not familiar with that. I wonder whether it is possible to extract the loss info info in each step and plot it use other plotting package or scikit-learn?

Really appreciated!

Comment: as a fellow noob to Tensorflow who just figured out tensor board, I would highly highly recommend taking the time to learn and set it up. It is a really awesome tool to speed up iterations of your network design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `sess.run(training_function, feed_dict)` statement so it includes your loss function as well. Then use something like Matplotlib to plot the data.

```
_, loss = sess.run((training_function, loss_function), feed_dict)
loss_list.append(loss)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(loss_list)
```

Comment: What would loss_function look like?