# How to plot accuracy curve in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/01_Simple_Linear_Model.ipynb) to build a simple network for MNIST classification. I want to plot the loss and accuracy curves for the same. I saw [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978117/how-to-plot-loss-curve-in-tensorflow-without-using-tensorboard) and got a nice loss curve. But I can't figure how to do the same for accuracy. I tried the following code in the `optimise function`

```
session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
if i % 100 == 0:
    loss=session.run(cost, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
    acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
    loss_list.append(loss)
    acc_list.append(acc)
    plt.plot(loss_list,acc_list)
```

and got error

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y_true_cls' with dtype int64 and shape [?]
>        [[node y_true_cls (defined at :2) ]]

For some reason I am unable to run `accuracy` inside the `optimise function`. How do I get the accuracy curve?

Comment: Your error state that you need to provide second value. Consider adding full code to your question

Comment: @Sharky code is same as in the GitHub link, I've just added the extra code in the optimise function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**y_true_cls** States that you need to give true class labels. From the blog which you have mentioned:-

```
feed_dict_test = {x: data.x_test,
                  y_true: data.y_test,
                  y_true_cls: data.y_test_cls}
def print_accuracy():
    # Use TensorFlow to compute the accuracy.
    acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_test)

    # Print the accuracy.
    print("Accuracy on test-set: {0:.1%}".format(acc))
```

As you can see accuracy is fed **feed_dict_test** which has y_true_cls which is "True_Labels". **Only with the help of predicted and True class labels we can find Accuracy.**

Comment: oh yes. That is why the error. But how do I get the accuracy curve then?